# How to monitor the local Java process using jconsole

Tags: monitoring

I am using jconsole to monitor Java program deployed in tomcat server. If I want to monitor it as a local process which one should I monitor either eclipse or the tomcat server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jconsole to monitor local as well as remote java applications. Local java processes are listed as shown below
[image: JConsole Local Process]

You can select the Process (or PID) to monitor from the list

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. But I would like to know if I need to monitor a process(java code in eclipse)  deployed on tomcat server I need to monitor only tomcat server

Comment: In such cases you have two instance of JVM , one is eclipse and other is tomcat. To monitor your code you have to monitor tomcat process.

Comment: Thank you so much Ramesh